# front-end Javascript (React) security (front-end value no trusted)

Tags: javascript, frontend, backend

I have a Node back-end and a front-end.
at the front-end (react) user can choose some features (screen one). Each time user adds a feature, front-end request from back-end new product price based on the features. selected features and product price are saved on react's state.

On second screen (payment details) there is a review of the product (features, price) where user adds his shipping details and can click on place order.

for creating that order i should not trust the state.price of the product , since easily someone with react tool can change state.price's value.

So on screen one When i send the featuers in back-end and it respond with new price. I should create a transaction id and attach the features and price for that customer and on second screen I just send the shipping details to be attached in that record.
Or on screen 2 send features and shipping details from react state but DONT trust the price, recalculate the price on back-end and only then create a transaction with an id with customer details and product details attached?

(first option back-end will fill the db with a transaction id that might not be needed if customer wouldn't complete screen 2)

Or is there another way that should be followed?

Comment: Whether to choose option 1 or 2 it's up to you, accordingly to the project scope. I'd choose option 1 so you can also send a reminder for users that did not complete the checkout

Comment: Always use backend calculation as source, and as you already mentioned, creating a transaction is overkill when a user never continues to the next screen. So I'd recommend sending the features again instead.

Comment: Although @Enrico's comment make sense if this is for authenticated users

Comment: im not sure how to answer this question.  I find it sort of opinion based. How I would answer and accomplish it i feel is different than others.  That being said, I would store a product_id, and quantity only.  It saves more space locally and then when you are at checkout, do a fetch of items, their respective prices, and a transaction_id. Then when a client would submit buy the only thing pushed up is transaction_id, a session_guid, personal info, payment info.